# Migrate root filesystem from btrfs to ext4

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, migration

I want migrate a Ubuntu installation off of btrfs as root because it frequently hangs and causes out of space errors and I really don't need the snapshots. The partition was created empty and not migrated so `btrfs convert -r` is not an option. The solution is probably to rsync the contents to another ext4 partition, but I never got that to boot (probably because of Grub/fstab/...). What do you need to move from btrfs to ext4 as root partition?

Comment: What is your question? Seems to me you need to backup your data and format the disk to ext4. Seems to trivial for an answer?!

Comment: I don't want to reinstall the system because it has a LOT of configured software and other stuff on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rsync the files to another, but it won't boot (as you've observed). However, it's not difficult to set the new drive to boot after you've copied the files. The exact method depends on which boot loader you want (grub, gummi, etc.), how you've configured your partitions (do you have a separate /boot partition?), if you're using partition tables or GPT, and if you're using EFI or MBR.

That's too many variables for me to cover, but you can find instructions online if you search. The Arch wiki pages tend to cover this in great detail, for example.

In case you're unsure, I suggest you choose GPT, EFI, no separate /boot partition, and gummi. If your system is old enough it may not support those choices.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. In a simple scenario (no separate boot partition, legacy BIOS boot) what would be needed to be able to boot the rsync'd partition?

Comment: Presuming you already have a partition table and have copied the data, you'll need to set the boot flag on the partition (any partition editor can do this, such as gparted). Next, `grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --debug /dev/sdx` where sdx is your new drive (use `lsblk` to see your drives). Finally, `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/newDrive/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. That should do the trick, but if not, refer to the Ubuntu [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) for other instructions including boot-repair.

Comment: Can you add the instructions for this specific place as a side note in the original answer so as to augment it?